# helpers python | NameError: name 'helpers' is not defined

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, helper

[error screenshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgg8c.png)

i'm trying to list a map using 'helpers' in python. but it is giving me error
NameError: name 'helpers' is not defined

----> 4 processed_data = list(map(helpers.process_tweet, data))

NameError: name 'helpers' is not defined

Comment: And what is that `helpers` supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is expecting `helpers` to be a defined variable. However, it is not, hence the error. This looks like a Jupyter Notebook, perhaps you forgot to run a higher cell that defines the `helper` variable?